# Infopath 2007 form not displaying changes

Tags: forms, infopath-2007

I have an InfoPath 2007 form that is behaving quite oddly.
I created it, published to a Sharepoint document library, running smoothly. Now, if I make changes to the form, I don't see them reflected after publishing. If I rename the xsn file to a cab and open the xsl, I can't also see the changes there, but in the Infopath editor I can see the changes.

I tried deleting the cache to no avail.

I also get an error trying to save the file: "User will not be able to open this form because of the security level it requires and because no alternate access path has been specified.". Even with the error the changes get saved, but that may be causing something not to be properly updated by InfoPath.

Any idea on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by selecting Tools -> Default Values, in InfoPath.
I'm not sure what this did but after it the changes were properly published.

There is something definitely wrong with InfoPath 2007...